# Jquery complementary functions not working as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two complementary functions, one that publishes a post, and one that unpublishes a post when the user clicks the same button (the button is acting as a toggle). If the post is not published and the user goes to publish it everything works as it is supposed to, however if the user decides to unpublish it again the function to publish is erroneously called again. I am using class selectors to accomplish this. So publish does its business and then sets the class to unpublish so that when the user clicks the button unpublish gets called (which doesn't happen).

I have verified that publish gets the class unpublish after being called, and vise versa but the complementary function never gets called despite having its class changed in the final lines. Console.log shows that publish keeps getting called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('a.publish').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('publish item');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var table = $(this).attr('rel');
        var parent = $(this).closest('.btn-group');
        var current = $(this).closest('a');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: 'publish=' + id + '&table=' + table,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#published_' + id).hide().html(data).fadeIn();
                count(table);
                var buttons = parent.find(".btn-danger");
                buttons.each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-primary");
                });
                current.find('span').text('Unpublish');
                current.removeClass("publish").addClass("unpublish");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('a.unpublish').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('unpublish item');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var table = $(this).attr('rel');
        var parent = $(this).closest('.btn-group');
        var current = $(this).closest('a');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: 'unpublish=' + id + '&table=' + table,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#published_' + id).hide().html(data).fadeIn();
                count(table);
                var buttons = parent.find(".btn-primary");
                buttons.each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
                });
                current.find('span').text('Publish');
                current.removeClass("unpublish").addClass("publish");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

If this has to do with DOM or something, how can I subvert it?

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary unpublish" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="213114246" rel="projects">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span class="actions">Unpublish</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Check your console.

Comment: I did (see before code), hence my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn-container').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('publish')) {
      console.log('publish item');
      $(this).removeClass("publish").addClass("unpublish").text('unpublish');
  } else {
      console.log('unpublish item');
      $(this).removeClass("unpublish").addClass("publish").text('publish');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-container">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary unpublish">unpublish</a>
</div>
```